# exporting project with native libraries in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, leap-motion

I have a project that uses leap motion sdk. I wrote this project in Eclipse. When I run my program I don't have any problem because I set my native libraries as it is suggested from configuration.

However, when I export my application I can not run my program because Eclipse does not include my native libraries and I am having this error.

```
Native code library failed to load. 
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no LeapJava in java.library.path
```

My purpose is create a .jar file which user can run with one click on Windows(just). I tried this methodologies as it is suggested in stackoverflow. However, I could not get this result.

1.) `method with static{ System.load("write each .dll") }`

This did not work becuse I am having a error when I try to load Leapd.dll.

2.) `System.setProperty("java.library.path", "C:/Users/can/Desktop/Vinar_libraries/LeapSDK/lib/x64/" );`

This one also did not work.

3.) Adding -Djava.library.path="\LeapSDK\lib\x64" parameter from running configurations on Eclipse.

I know this subject is mentioned many times in stackoverflow. However, proposed solutions did not work for Leap Motion sensor.

Comment: System.setProperty("java.library.path",/LeapSDK/lib/x64/" ); 
Field fieldSysPath = null;
fieldSysPath = ClassLoader.class.getDeclaredField( "sys_paths" );
fieldSysPath.setAccessible( true );
fieldSysPath.set( null, null );

When I wrote this code, it is working if I run my jar from command line. However, it does not run when I click on my .jar.

Comment: I recently heard about this project: http://ninjacave.com/jarsplice, which could be a solution. -- Also, you should use "Leap.dll" not "Leapd.dll".